# Spring Boot - Autowiring a DataSource Bean

Tags: spring, spring-boot, autowired

I have a basic Spring Boot application annotated like this:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class ApiApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(ApiApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

I have the following entries in my `application.properties` file:

```
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.postgresql.Driver
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/db
spring.datasource.username=dbuser
spring.datasource.password=dbpassword
```

From my understanding Spring Boot should be able to automatically autowire a DataSource Bean from these properties.

However if I try:

```
@Autowired
DataSource dataSource;
```

anywhere in my application (f.i. in @Configuration files), I get the following error in IntelliJ:

> "Could not autowire. No beans of 'DataSource' type found."

Is there something obvious that I'm missing for this to work?

I have a single DataSource.

Comment: @EnableAutoConfiguration should also be added on top of the main class.

Comment: `@SpringBootApplication` supposedly also adds `@EnableAutoConfiguration`. I tried adding it manually but that didn't fix the error.

Comment: If that is the case, enable debug level logs for spring boot and check what happens to DataSource bean.

Comment: IntelliJ has excellent Spring support but it's not always up to date.  For example the last time I checked it still doesn't recognize Spring Data repositories that are not annotated.  They used to require annotation, however that is no longer the case if they extend an appropriate interface.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The bean actually does get initialized correctly. This is possibly just an IntelliJ tooltip bug.

Adding @SuppressWarnings to hide the message will work without further issues.

Comment: that is right, just had the same issue  - even in IntelliJ IDEA 2017.1.3 Build #IU-171.4424.56, built on May 12, 2017 this still exists. The beans are wired correctly even though IntelliJ warns about conflict

Answer (score 2):

Intelij apparently even in the 2016.2 still does not support the @SpringBootApplication annotation. You either have to remove the @SpringBootApplication annotation and replace it with the  @Configuration, @EnableAutoConfiguration and @ComponentScan annotations or just ignore the errors.